# To show / replace an another DIV from existing DIV tag on the same page while using data-role="page">

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, android-emulator

**Need:** To show / replace an another DIV from existing DIV tag on the same page  while using data-role="page">

**Problem**: While using hide/show method to the div for displaying the next page  reg button(click)=>reg DIV content> but the Reg DIV Content is displayed for only 2 sec, and then the apps is exited and comes to the main menu in Emulator.

**Code_STRUCTURE**: (as i mentioned below)

```
   <div id="page" data-role="page">
     <div id="header" data-role="header">
     </div>
     <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <div id="log_in"> <!-- 1st content <div> -->
        </div>
        <!-- need to replace -->
        <div id="reg"> <!-- 2nd content <div> -->
        </div>

        <!-- other <Div> with same procedure-->
     </div> <!-- content END -->
     <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
     </div>
  </div> <!-- page -->

 // in J query call
 // to show reg content then call
 $('#log_in').hide(); // or also tried as $('#log_in').css('display','none');
 $('#reg').show();   // or also tried as $('#reg').css('display','block');
```

**Platform**   : Android
**Compiled in**: Eclipse Emulator

If any one have the answer, please post it! and if you prefer to give any more suggests and also be knowledgeable. Thank you for visiting this post!

Edited: (my old Code)

```
  <div id="page" data-role="page">
 <div id="header" data-role="header">
 </div>
 <div id="content" data-role="content">
    <div id="log_in"> <!-- 1st content <div> -->
      <form>
         <input><!-- something goes here-->
         <button id="login">Login</button>
         <button id="reg">Register</button>
      **</form>**
    </div>
    <!-- need to replace -->
    <div id="reg"> <!-- 2nd content <div> -->
    </div>

    <!-- other <Div> with same procedure-->
 </div> <!-- content END -->
 <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
 </div>
```

(Corrected Code):

```
    <div id="page" data-role="page">
 <div id="header" data-role="header">
 </div>
 <div id="content" data-role="content">
    <div id="log_in"> <!-- 1st content <div> -->
      <form>
         <input><!-- something goes here-->
      **</form>**

         <button id="login">Login</button>
         <button id="reg">Register</button>
              </div>
    <!-- need to replace -->
    <div id="reg"> <!-- 2nd content <div> -->
    </div>

    <!-- other <Div> with same procedure-->
 </div> <!-- content END -->
 <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most certainly with your js code.

You should be able to successfully use both jQuery `show()`/`hide()` and `display: none;`.

**[Here is working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LwVzF/)**

Comment: Thank You brother (Peterm), the link from your answer is also worked in android emulator. But while i need to include some other code's then it reflected as the problem, that i was mentioned in earlier. I think the code may be conflict, and i need to re-organize of that.Any way thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Jai You're certainly welcome. If it was helpful, please, consider to [accept/up vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. Happy coding.

Comment: I found the reason for my problem:(old Code:)

Comment: <div id="page" data-role="page">
     <div id="header" data-role="header">
     </div>
     <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <div id="log_in"> <!-- 1st content <div> -->
        </div>
        <!-- need to replace -->
        <div id="reg"> <!-- 2nd content <div> -->
        </div>

        <!-- other <Div> with same procedure-->
     </div> <!-- content END -->
     <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
     </div>
  </div> <!-- page --

Comment: Bcz i just used the two buttons inside of before </form> element is closed
so that when the form tries to take action while change the page/ content then it conflicted and the apps is exited

Comment: If i use those (login, reg) of the buttons, outside of the <form> then it works fine! Thank you.